# Best way to call object created in Listener class in other parts of the application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ehcache

I am working on an application developed using Servlet and spring. 
Below is the code followed by the description.

```
package com.mymodule.listener;
import net.sf.ehcache.*;
//imports
public class MyInitializationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    /** Singleton instance of CacheManager. */
    private static CacheManager singletonManager = null;

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("--ServletContextListener destroyed*--");
    }
    private static CacheManager getInstance() {
        if (singletonManager == null) {
            singletonManager = CacheManager.create();
        }
        return singletonManager;
    }

    private Cache getCache() {
        Cache cache = null;
        cache = MyInitializationListener.getInstance().getCache("myCache");
        return cache;
    }
    // Run this before web application is started

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    final Cache cache = getCache();
        //logic here

      }
```

Above is my Listener class which gets loaded as soon as the server is started. I have created the ehcache object in the above class. My requirement is as below:

Connect to the database and get the value.
Store the value in cache , so that any further request to that value is retrieved from a cache instead of a database hit.
But the issue is when the above Listener is initialized during server startup, my other XML files where I have configured the data sources are not yet started.So I cannot write any database logic in my Listener class. To solve this issue I have to write the database logic in other class and that class is present in other packages.

```
package com.mymodule.dao.hibernate;
public class MyDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements MyDAO {


    public String getDataValue() throws DataLayerException {

    //String SQL = "...";
    //logic to connect to the database and get the value.
    //here I want to get that ehcache object which was created after the server is started in MyInitializerListener class.

}
```

Please suggest which would be the best possible way and how to get the ehcache object in other classes of the application present in different packages. The value returned from the database table is being used in many parts of the application , and that's the reason I want to store that value in ehcache and call from the cache whenever required.

Answer (score 0):

Create a getter method like this:

```
public MyObject getMyObject()
{
        return myObjectInstance;
}
```

Then you will be able to get the object from any class that creates an instance of the listener. If you need to get it into a class that doesn't create an instance of the listener, you can still use this, as long as the  requesting class has a reference to a class that can reference a class (...) that has access to an instance of the listener.

For example, if You had a class that needs the object and has an instance of the class that instantiated the listener, you could just create a getter method inside both the listener and the class that created it:

In the listener:

```
public MyObject getMyObject()
{
   return myObject;
}
```

In the class that created the listener:

```
public MyObject getMyObjectFromListener()
{
        return listenerInstance.getMyObject();
}
```

It's dirty, but it should work.

Comment: user2465510  - So u want me to create listenerInstance as : MyInitializationListener  listenerInstance = new MyInitializationListener  () in the class where I want to get the object from listener. But not sure is that the best possible way to follow..Please advice.

Comment: Do you need to create an instance of the listener, such as for a addListener() method? Then I think it should work. I'm not really familiar with servlets so I'm not 100% certain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring, the correct way is to make the `CacheManager` or the `Cache` proper Spring beans.

Once that is achieved you will be able to inject them in the places that require them, whether it is a `ServletContextListener` or you DAO implementation.